# Execute variable inside a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a ruby on rails developer and have a simple question which I am not able to figure out.

```
location.href = "/home?selected_date="+selecteddate;"&days_ago="+dateDiff(selecteddate , todaysdate);
```

I have to generate a URL by using the above code, here I have a variable called *selecteddate* which generates a value and *dateDiff(selecteddate , todaysdate);* does a difference of the selected date and today's date and gives me a value.

**Question:** When I execute it my URL looks like this:

```
/home?selected_date=Sun Sep 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

I am missing the &days_ago= part. Any Idea how parse two parameters in the URL.

Thanks you in advance

Comment: notice the semicolon after selecteddate variable replace it with + sign

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass the date in that format? You could use selecteddate.getTime() to pass it in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is off. Plus you should encode it:

```
location.href = "/home?selected_date=" + encodeURIComponent(selecteddate) + "&days_ago=" + encodeURIComponent(dateDiff(selecteddate , todaysdate));
```

Comment: @Sergio yep, without it the URL will still be broken. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think it should be encodeURIComponent not encodeUriComponent if I am not wrong

Answer (score 0):

you missed to concatenate.

```
location.href = "/home?selected_date="+selecteddate+";&days_ago="+dateDiff(selecteddate , todaysdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
location.href = "/home?selected_date="+selecteddate+"&days_ago="+dateDiff(selecteddate , todaysdate);
```

The problem is that you're not concatenate the `selecteddate` string variable.